# Destructuring object react native hooks from firebase returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, firebase, react-native

This is a video recording app Im working on and after uploading to firebase in an array it then I have it logged on the console.log bellow. 
I am new to React Hooks and all, would really appraciate some help!

I have been unable to destructure this, I need the uri values in separate variable so it can be outputted in a `<Video/>` component within a `<FlatList/>`.

Here is the array that needs to be destructured:
Note: I changed the key/uri values here for simplification.

```
 Array [
  Array [
    Object {
      "key": "0001",
      "video": Object {
        "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/...",
      },
    },
    Object {
      "key": "0002",
      "video": Object {
        "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/...",
      },
    },
  ],
]
```

Here is what I tried... 
`const values = videoArray.uir;
console.log("uirs",values);`

Here is all the code bellow:
Note: I've commented out the Flatlist, but I want the uri to output there...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { FlatList, View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { Center } from '../components/Center'
import { Video } from 'expo-av';
import firebase from '../firebase'
const videoRef = firebase.database().ref('videoCollaction');

export const FeedScreen = ({ }) => {

    var [videoArray, setVideo] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      const videoArray = []; // temp array
      videoRef.on("value", childSnapshot => {
        childSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            videoArray.push({
            key: doc.key,
            video: doc.toJSON().video
          });
        });
        setVideo(videoArray); // update state array
      });
    }, []);

       //get uri value from videoArray array...
        const values = videoArray.uir;



    return (
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Text>Feed Screen</Text>
             //log uir only 
             {console.log("uirs",values)}
            {/* array values here */}
            {console.log(" display Array",[videoArray])}

            {/* <FlatList
                data={[videoArray]}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                    return (
                        <View>

                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 35, color: 'red' }}>Video: {item.uri}</Text>


                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('pressed')}><Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}>Expand</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    );
                }} keyExtractor={({ item }, index) => index.toString()}>
            </FlatList> */}


            <Video
                source={{ uri: {videoArray} }}
                // shouldPlay={this.state.shouldPlay}
                // isMuted={this.state.mute}
                resizeMode="cover"
                style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
                useNativeControls={true}
                isLooping={true}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```

Here is the async function from another file, where the data is being pushed to firebase (another file, within in an onPress function).

```
async () => {
              // if recording
              if (!recording) {
                setRecording(true)
                video = await cameraRef.recordAsync();
                //console.log('video', { video });

                //trigger firebase push array 
                videoRef.push({ 
                  //push video
                  video,
                 }).then((data)=>{
                     //success callback
                     console.log('data ' , data)
                 }).catch((error)=>{
                     //error callback
                     console.log('error ' , error)
                 })
                .then(console.log('new video: ', {video}), alert('video added'));

              } else {
                setRecording(false)
                cameraRef.stopRecording()
              }
            }
```

Here is a screenshot of the videoArray values in console. 
[image]

Not sure why it's so complicated, would really appreciate some help.

**UPDATE:** Ive fixed the array, now it's a matter of getting the uir 
values.

Here is the updated array:

```
after use effect Array [
  Object {
    "key": "-M40wgjXtE4utZUH37Fn",
    "video": Object {
      "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6D4BF03E-4E53-481A-AF86-55C6B702B6B0/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540ameer_devking%252Fspark-app/Camera/BADB80A8-27E9-4BDD-9779-81CC356B6F93.mov",
    },
  },
  Object {
    "key": "-M40wofZn8k81mE4DMb4",
    "video": Object {
      "uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6D4BF03E-4E53-481A-AF86-55C6B702B6B0/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540ameer_devking%252Fspark-app/Camera/320B6F55-81F3-42A1-83C7-DE5F988F64B4.mov",
    },
  },
]
```

Here was the code I used to get the uir values, got error 
`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'videoArray[1].map')`

Code used:

```
 const videoUris = videoArray[0].map(video => video.uri);
 console.log("URIS:",videoUris);
```

Comment: This looks like an async issue. It's a bit hard to understand what's going on because your code sample is a bit convoluted, but it seems like you might set some part of the videoArray object (it's an object by the way, not an array) in the videoRef.on callback, but you use it outside of it. I recommend you work through the order of execution a bit. If you still need help, I recommend simplifying the code example and letting us know what variable contains what values at what point.

Comment: Hi @dreamLand70 Are you sure that your returned data structure look like this: `[.[.{..}.].]`? usually it should return like `[.{..}.]` ( Array > Object) not nested arrays.

Comment: @awran5 you're right and not sure why it was returned like that. I can post a screen shot if that would be helpful

Comment: Yes please. Also, you can `console.log(videoArray)` just after the `useEffect` and before `return`

Comment: @awran5 okey I've added it, and logged `videoArray` after `useEffect` too. I resolved `[.[.{..}.].]` I had an extra par of `[]` which where not needed, now it looks right. Now the challenge is to get the uir value for the array. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Ive updated the question. Appreciate you taking time to help!

Comment: Hey @dreamLand70 Please check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-flatlist-rzndf)

Comment: @awran5 I looked at it, you created the `datass` object with my array, but I don't see you structuring it anywhere to get the uri values.

Comment: Sorry :) just realized that it wasn't saved for some reason. its updated now.

Comment: thanks again for the help !

Answer (score 0):

How to destructure and get the uri's:

```
   const videoUris = videoArray.map(item=> item.video.uri)
   console.log(videoUris);
```

Add to FlatList, example found in the comments of this post. 
[Click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-flatlist-rzndf)

Comment: yes it is working as needed and now have a list of videos in the flat list. Thank you so much!